# String parsing techniques

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing

I am trying to find a good way to parse a message string into an object. 
The string is of fixed length and described below.

[image: Snippet of string spec]

- protocol = int(2)
- message type = string(1)
- measurement = string(4)
- etc

Doing a simple `String.Split` will work, but I think may be a bit cumbersome when you start to get towards the end of the string. e.g.:

```
var field1 = s.SubString(0,2);
var field2 = s.SubString(2,4);
....
var field99 = s.SubString(88,4); // difficult magic numbers
```

I considered using a Regex and thought that maybe even more confusing.

I was trying to think of an elegant solution, where I could create a Parser which was passed a 'config' that would detail how to parse the string.

Something like...

```
 MyConfig config = new MyConfig()
 config.Add("Protocol",    Length=2, typeof(int));
 config.Add("MessageType", Length=1, typeof(char));


 Parser p = new Parser(config);
 var parserResult = p.Parse(message);
```

...but I'm going around in circles at the minute and not getting anywhere. Any pointers would be a great help.

Comment: Use regex for each one separatly.  It will be simple and not confusing

Comment: `Regex` with capture groups is probably the way I'd go about it if I'm honest

Comment: Regex is the proper tool to extract and parse string. A Regex group maps to MyConfig except type and why do you build your own? However, I don't know how do you leverage type here. Do you have a big switch? It's true that Regex is hard to read but you can construct it carefully with many comments. Split it in pieces and it will not be confusing at all.

Comment: I recently answer a similar question.  I created a function that parsed a fixed width string using an input array like this string[] tabLocations = {1,20,30,50,70};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a regex is confusing if done the right way. You can use named capturing groups and you can define it quite neatly (example is for the first three fields, which you can extend as much as you want):

```
const string GRP_PROTOCOL = "protocol";
const string GRP_MESSAGE_TYPE = "msgtype";
const string GRP_MEASUREMENT = "measurement";

Regex parseRegex = new Regex(
    $"(?<{GRP_PROTOCOL}>.{{2}})" +
    $"(?<{GRP_MESSAGE_TYPE}>.{{1}})" +
    $"(?<{GRP_MEASUREMENT}>.{{4}})");
```

You can also define your groups and their lengths in an array:

```
const string GRP_PROTOCOL = "protocol";
const string GRP_MESSAGE_TYPE = "msgtype";
const string GRP_MEASUREMENT = "measurement";

Tuple<string, int>[] groups = {
    Tuple.Create( GRP_PROTOCOL, 2 ),
    Tuple.Create( GRP_MESSAGE_TYPE, 1 ),
    Tuple.Create( GRP_MEASUREMENT, 4 )
};

Regex parseRegex =
    new Regex(String.Join("", groups.Select(grp => $"(?<{grp.Item1}>.{{{grp.Item2}}})").ToArray()));
```

You can then access the groups by name whenever you need them:

```
Match match = parseRegex.Match(message);
string protocol = match.Groups[GRP_PROTOCOL].Value;
string msgType = match.Groups[GRP_MESSAGE_TYPE].Value;
string measurement = match.Groups[GRP_MEASUREMENT].Value;
```

Comment: It's not `parseRegex.Groups` but `match.Groups`. And you have a missing `;` after your `Tuple`.

Answer (score 4):

So a simple message structure:

```
class Message
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public int Protocol { get; set; }
    public string Measurement { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    //....
}
```

Combined with a class that knows how to deserialize it:

```
class MessageSerializer
{
    public Message Deserialize(string str)
    {
        Message message = new Message();
        int index = 0;
        message.Protocol = DeserializeProperty(str, ref index, 2, Convert.ToInt32);
        message.Type = DeserializeProperty(str, ref index, 1, Convert.ToString);
        message.Measurement = DeserializeProperty(str, ref index, 4, Convert.ToString);
        message.DateTime = DeserializeProperty<DateTime>(str, ref index, 16, (s) =>
        {
            // Parse date time from 2013120310:28:55 format
            return DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMMddhh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        });
        //...
        return message;
    }

    static T DeserializeProperty<T>(string str, ref int index, int count, 
        Func<string, T> converter)
    {
        T property = converter(str.Substring(index, count));
        index += count;
        return property;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the properties inside the input string are fixed-width then Regex is overhead in both implementation and performance terms. An idea of creating a generic parser is good, but it makes sense if you have multiples parsers to implement. So there are no reasons to have an abstraction if there is only one particular implementation.

I would go with just `StringReader`:

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(input)) {
}
```

...and then creating a few helper extension methods like these:

```
// just a sample code, to get the idea

public static string ReadString(this TextReader reader, int count)
{
    var buffer = new char[count];
    reader.Read(buffer, 0, count);
    return string.Join(string.Empty, buffer);
}

public static int ReadNumeric(this TextReader reader, int count)
{
    var str = reader.ReadString(count);
    int result;
    if (int.TryParse(str, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    // handle error
}

// ...
```

and final usage would be like this:

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(input)) {
    var protocol = reader.ReadNumeric(2);
    var messageType = reader.ReadString(1);
    var measurement = reader.ReadString(4);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be: `GetNextCharacters(int position,int length, out newPosition)` which gives you next `length` characters, the string you wanted, and new position for next call.

That way you only change the `length` in each call.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class with properties for each string section, and a custom attribute (Ex. FieldItem) that specify the start/end positions, in the constructor you can pass the whole string, then write some internal logic based on the properties attributes (using reflection) to load each property from the provided string (a ReadString method maybe, or whatever), based on SubString(start,end) usage with indexes taken from the custom attribute.
It's more clean this way, I think, than by defining special regex, plus you can easily change the field definitions by just editing the attribute properties.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to leverage the [`TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It can accept a list of field lengths for use in parsing.

```
using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(s))){
     parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.FixedWidth;
     parser.SetFieldWidths(2,1,4 /*etc*/);
     while (!parser.EndOfData)
     {
         var data = parser.ReadFields(); //string[]
     }
}
```

However this would only split out your data into an array of strings. If all your types were `IConvertible`, you could possibly do something like...

```
var types = new[] {typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(DateTime), /*etc..*/ };
var data = parser.ReadFields();
var firstVal = Convert.ChangeType(data[0], types[0]); 
var secondVal = Convert.ChangeType(data[1], types[1]); 
// etc..
// or in a loop: 
for (var i = 0; i<data.Length;++i){
  var valAsString = data[i];
  var thisType = types[i];
  var value = Convert.ChangeType(valAsString , thisType);
  // do something with value
}
```

though `Convert.ChangeType` returns an `object` so the type of your variables would be of type `object` as well unless you were to cast them:

```
var firstVal = (int)Convert.ChangeType(data[0], types[0]);
// because unfortunately this is not valid:
var firstVal = (types[0])Convert.ChangeType(data[0], types[0]);
```

You *might* be able to leverage `dynamic` keyword in this case, though my experience with it is very little and I'm not sure it makes a difference:

`dynamic firstVal = Convert.ChangeType(data[0], types[0]);`

Note that there are performance penalties involved with both the `dynamic` keyword as well as the `TextFieldParser` class which has been documented to not be the most performant (just see other SO posts on this matter), at least with larger strings/files. Of course the use of `TextFieldParser` may also be overkill for your case if all you are ever doing is parsing a single string.

If you have a dto/poco class that represents this data, you could always pass the string array returned by `ReadFields()` into a constructor on your dto that can populate the data for you... ie:

```
class Message {
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public int Protocol { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Measurement {get;set;}
    public Message(string[] data) {
       Protocol = int.Parse(data[0]);
       Type = data[1];
       Measurement = data[2];
       DateTime = DateTime.Parse(data[3]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said if your string is static you can use marshal class, like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 1)]
public struct TData
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 2)]
    public protocol string;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst =1)]
    public messageType string;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    public measurement 
...
    public int getProtocol(){return Convert.ToInt32(protocol);}
...
}

public string get(){
   var strSource="03EMSTR...";
    IntPtr pbuf = Marshal.StringToBSTR(buf);
    TData data= (TData)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pbuf,typeof(TData))
}
```

I think this method can make your code very pure and maintainable.